# Location duplicate point data display logic in Google earth

Tags: google-earth

I have two or more location duplicate point data in my KML. In google earth I can only see one point data at first. When I click it and then its separated, and able to click other duplicate point.

My problem is that I don't know the logic which point is front in the first place.  I need specific point data to be at front before it's separated because of visual perspective. I try to change placemarks order in KML but the result was same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know the logic which duplicate point data will be front in Google earth. I hope it's not random...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to control which point's ICON shows up at a location with multiple points, before you click on it to expand/separate them all out? Unfortunately there is no way that I know of to control which point/icon shows up on top. It seems like when I create or edit points at the same location, the last one to be touched/edited comes out on top, but I don't know if that's consistent, nor whether it persists when saved to KML... probably not.